# How to compute $\chi_1$, a Lorentzian absorption in the following paper?

Tags: electromagnetism, condensed-matter, solid-state-physics

I have the following paper:
https://arxiv.org/abs/1508.01213
on the third page, where they take: $$\chi_2(\omega)= \frac{-k\gamma}{(\omega-\omega_0)^2+\gamma^2},$$ I don't see how to explicitly compute $\chi_1$.

Can someone please show me the way?

Comment: Did you try to use the Kramers-Kronig relation as advised in the paper?

Answer (score 1):

I realised after writing this that the OP probably doesn't need this answer any more, but anyway:

You need to use the [Kramers-Kronig relations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kramers%E2%80%93Kronig_relations) which connect the real and imaginary parts of any complex function $\chi(\omega) = \chi_1(\omega) + i \chi_2(\omega)$ that is analytic in the upper half-plane.

In particular, the relation you need (as described in the paper) is:

$$\chi_1(\omega) = \frac{1}{\pi} \mathcal{P} \int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{\chi_2(\omega')}{\omega'-\omega} \text{d}\omega',$$

where $\mathcal{P}$ denotes the "[Cauchy principal value](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_principal_value)".